# Weird Swift's #selector behavior. Value of parameter totally different through #selector

Tags: ios, swift, timer, selector

I'm new to Swift's #selector paradigm. Ultimately I'm trying to move SKSpriteNode of a spaceShip over an CGMutablePath and add exhaust fumes as SKEmitterNodes on the path that the spaceShip has travelled.

However I'm stuck on #selector paradigm. I'm trying to send position of a the SpaceShipSprite via a timer to a `addFumeToPosition(_ point: CGPoint)` function so later I can add the SKEmitternode to that position.

For some reason that I cannot comprehend the #selector thing sends out something totally different than what I'm putting into the variable. Please see prints below. What's going on here?

```
let spaceShipSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "spaceShip")))

spaceShipSprite.position = CGPoint(x: 142.0, y:160.0)
spaceShipSprite.name = "spaceShip"
self.addChild(spaceShipSprite)

print("spaceShipSprite.position before timer point x:\(spaceShipSprite.position.x) y:\(spaceShipSprite.position.y)")

let gameTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector:#selector(addFumeToPosition(_: )), userInfo: spaceShipSprite.position, repeats: true)

print("spaceShipSprite.position before timer point x:\(spaceShipSprite.position.x) y:\(spaceShipSprite.position.y)")
```

...

```
func addFumeToPosition(_ point: CGPoint){
        print("spaceShipSprite.position during point x:\(point.x) y:\(point.y)")
}
```

spaceShipSprite.position before timer point x:142.0 y:160.0

spaceShipSprite.position after timer point x:142.0 y:160.0

spaceShipSprite.position during timer point x:196092657881833.0 y:1000000000.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that.

The two supported forms of target/action are

- Without parameter

  ```
  func addFumeToPosition()
  ```
- With one parameter representing the affected class (in this case the `Timer` instance)

  ```
  func addFumeToPosition(_ timer: Timer)
  ```

If a parameter is passed it must be the `Timer` instance.

All custom parameters have to be passed and handled via the `userInfo` parameter.

```
func addFumeToPosition(_ timer: Timer){
    let point = timer.userInfo as! CGPoint
    print("spaceShipSprite.position during point x:\(point.x) y:\(point.y)")
}
```

Note: In Swift 4 you might have to add the `@objc` attribute to the function.

Comment: You should clarify that those two forms are specific to the target/action of a `Timer`.